# jQuery next 5 sibilings

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you think of a calendar look a like view. Each dayHolder have a data-date property.
If I then pick one fromDate and one untilDate from a datepicker calender. Then im calculating how many days it is between fromDate and untilDate, later I finds my fromDate in my own calender and write a status on this one, next I finds the next day and writes a status on that one, and continues on until a reached my untilDate -date.

What is the best way of doing this?
Feels like a dom-heavy thing to find each dayDiv with the data-date.

So I have done it like this for now:

```
var fromDate = new Date(calenderStatus.fromDate.substring(0, 10));
var untilDate = new Date(calenderStatus.untilDate.substring(0, 10));
var days = 0;

if (fromDate <= untilDate) {
    var smallDate = new Date(fromDate.getFullYear(), fromDate.getMonth(), fromDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var maxDays = new Date(untilDate.getFullYear(), untilDate.getMonth(), untilDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    days = (maxDays - smallDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
}

if (days > 0) {
    var dayHolder = $(".dayHolder[data-date='"+ calenderStatus.fromDate +"']");

    for (var i = 0; i < days; i++) {
        //do something with dayHolder
        dayHolder = dayHolder.next('.dayHolder');
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dayHolder ui-grid-a" data-changeable="true" data-date="2013-06-24">
<div class="dayHolder ui-grid-a" data-changeable="true" data-date="2013-06-25">
<div class="dayHolder ui-grid-a" data-changeable="true" data-date="2013-06-26">
```

Comment: To find `next 5 sibilings`, try `$(this).nextAll(':lt(5)')`

Comment: Worked fine! Found this: Because :lt() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :lt() cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use $("your-pure-css-selector").slice(0, index) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I made a comment that I got a question on.
This is the comment:

> Because :lt() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :lt() cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use $("your-pure-css-selector").slice(0, index) instead.

If I now gets all of my .dayHolder and would like to use the slice method. How would I find the index of the specific dayHolder with the right date-date. 
This is the one

```
var specificDiv = $(".dayHolder[data-date='"+ calenderStatus.fromDate +"']");
```

But what is that one's index in $('.dayHolder') ?

Like this:

```
$('.dayHolder').slice(specificDiv, 5)
```